# My click detection isnt working with 3rd Rect

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, im making a basic clicker game, im trying to add a CPS system (Clicks Per Second) so you can idle the game, but ive run into a problem, the system for click detection i have for some reason will not trigger on the 3rd rectangle i have set.
Code:

```
import pygame, os, sys, time, random
from random import randint
 
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
txtcolor = (200, 200, 200)
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 480))
 
pygame.init()
 
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
clicks = 0
cpsupp = 100
upp = 25
multi = 1
pos1 = 240 - 25/2
pos21 = 75
pos31 = 75
siz1 = 25 
siz21 = 25
siz31 = 25
pos2 = 240 - 25/2
pos22 = 75
pos32 = 150
siz2 = 25
siz22 = 25
siz32 = 25
rect = pygame.Rect(pos1, pos2, siz1, siz2)
rect.center = (240, 240)
rect2 = pygame.Rect(pos21, pos22, siz21, siz22)
rect3 = pygame.Rect(pos31, pos32, siz31, siz32)
fontlarge = pygame.font.SysFont(' ', 90)
fontmedium = pygame.font.SysFont(' ', 30)
fontsmall = pygame.font.SysFont(' ', 20)
fontvsmall = pygame.font.SysFont(' ', 15)
text = fontlarge.render(f'Clicks: {clicks}', True, txtcolor)
text2 = fontmedium.render(f'Upgrade price: {upp}', True, txtcolor)
text3 = fontsmall.render(f'CPS Upgrade price: {cpsupp}', True, txtcolor)
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect2 = text2.get_rect()
textRect3 = text3.get_rect()
textRect.center = (120, 20)
textRect2.center = (pos21 + 15, pos22 + 35)
textRect3.center = (pos31 + 15, pos32 + 35)

 
def clickcheck():
 global clicks
 global multi
 global upp
 mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
 print(mousex, mousey)
 if mousey >= pos1 and mousey <= pos1 + siz1:
   if mousex >= pos2 and mousex <= pos2 + siz2:
     print('Click-Rect')
     clicks += 1 * multi
 if mousey >= pos21 and mousey <= pos21 + siz21:
   if mousex >= pos22 and mousex <= pos22 + siz22:
     print('Click-Rect-2')
     if clicks >= upp:
       print('Upgrade')
       multi += 1
       clicks -= upp
       upp = round(upp * multi / 1.677)
 if mousey >= pos31 and mousey <= pos31 + siz31: # <---- PROBLEM!
   if mousex >= pos32 and mousex <= pos32 + siz32:
     print('Click-Rect-3')
 
while True:
  #event handler
  event = pygame.event.get()
  for ev in event:
    if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      clickcheck()
  surface.fill((black))
  pygame.draw.rect(surface, white, rect)
  pygame.draw.rect(surface, white, rect2)
  pygame.draw.rect(surface, white, rect3)
  text = fontlarge.render(f'Clicks: {clicks}', True, txtcolor)
  text2 = fontmedium.render(f'Upgrade price: {upp}', True, txtcolor)
  text3 = fontsmall.render(f'CPS Upgrade price: {cpsupp}', True, txtcolor)
  surface.blit(text, textRect)
  surface.blit(text2, textRect2)
  surface.blit(text3, textRect3)
  pygame.display.update()
```

Help would be appreicated, i cant find alot online about my issue

Comment: Can you try to create a [MCVE]?

Comment: You should just do `rect3.collidepoint(mousex, mousey)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the x and the y mixed up.

```
     #if mousey >= pos31 and mousey <= pos31 + siz31:
     if mousey >= pos32 and mousey <= pos32 + siz32:
         #if mousex >= pos32 and mousex <= pos32 + siz32:
         if mousex >= pos31 and mousex <= pos31 + siz31:  
             print('Click-Rect-3')
```

Comment: thank you! this solved the issue

Comment: Your welcome. Although this works, you should consider megalng's advice and use collidepoint.